# How to address the following error "To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change"?

Tags: matlab, reshape, cell-array

I want to convert a 2x2 cell into a simple 2x2 matrix in the code shown below. In doing so, I am facing the error mentioned in the title. The code is given below.

```
clc
close all
clear all

A = [0 1;-2 1];
B = [0;1];
Q = [2 6;6 5];
R = 0.25;
%x0 = [2;-3]; 
X0 = [1; 1; 1; 1];

Tf = 5;
tm = 0:0.1:Tf;

[T X] = ode45(@(t,X)mRiccati(t, X, A, B, Q, R), [0 Tf], X0)

[m n] = size(X);
P = mat2cell(X, ones(m,1), n);
fh_reshape = @(x)reshape(x,size(A));
P = cellfun(fh_reshape,P,'UniformOutput',false);
K= reshape(cat(1,P{:}),size(P))
```

---

```
function dXdt = mRiccati(t, X, A, B, Q, R)
X = reshape(X, size(A)); %Convert from "n^2"-by-1 to "n"-by-"n"
dXdt = A.'*X + X*A - X*B*inv(R)*B.'*X + Q; %Determine derivative
dXdt = dXdt(:); %Convert from "n"-by-"n" to "n^2"-by-1
end
```

The error is due to the line "K= reshape(cat(1,P{:}),size(P))". What is wrong here ?

Comment: Your matrix `cat(1,P{:})` is of size 146x2, while `size(P)` returns `[73 1]`. What shape do you want to make it?

Comment: P contains 73 2x2 matrices. `P{i}` will return you the `i`th 2x2 matrix. You cannot reshape 73 2x2 matrices into ones 2x2 matrix.